# High-water marks of a sequence

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, data

I need to write a function that is, given a sequence of integers, extracts the subsequence of its [high-water marks](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/High-WaterMark.html) (i.e. distinct values of its running maximum). Here are some naïve implementations that immediately come to mind:

```
HighWaterMarks[s_?VectorQ] := 
    Split[FoldList[Max, s]][[All, 1]]; (* slow *)

HighWaterMarks[s_?VectorQ] := 
    Drop[Fold[If[Last[#1] < #2, Append[#1, #2], #1] &, {-∞}, s], 1];

HighWaterMarks[s_?VectorQ] := 
    Reap[Block[{max = -∞}, Do[If[n > max, Sow[max = n]], {n, s}]]][[2, 1]];
```

Is there a simpler or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why not `DeleteDuplicates@FoldList[Max, s]`?

Comment: It is about as slow as my first version (about x1.5 slower than the other two). In general, `DeleteDuplicates` does not know that the input is a monotone sequence, where all equal elements are adjacent, and it needs to maintains a set of already encountered values.

Comment: Are you optimising for very long lists or lots of short lists?  Are your numbers in a random order, or might they tend to increase?  This tells you which branch you need to focus on.

Comment: In setting an optimisation challenge, it's a good idea to define the timing test to be used.

Comment: On my computer the `DeleteDuplicates` version is 4 - 10 times faster than the others. What kind of data are you testing on?

Comment: Am I missing something here? "...the input is a monotone sequence...", so `DeleteDuplicates@<input list>` does the same.

Comment: Who said monotone?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: See the quotes? It's the OP in comments. But now that I read the comments again, I think the OP is referring to the result of the `Fold`. Mea culpa.

Comment: The final *result* of the computation will be monotonic (of course)... but not the input.

Comment: See:  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/High-WaterMark.html and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RunningMaximum.html

Comment: @ciao Yes, I meant the result of folding with `Max` was monotone. The original sequence is not monotone; in my case it can contain about 10⁵ numbers, and the list of its high-water marks contains about 20 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For comparative timings, starting with a fresh kernel:

```
$Version

(* "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

HighWaterMarks[1][s_?VectorQ] :=
  Split[FoldList[Max, s]][[All, 1]];

HighWaterMarks[2][s_?VectorQ] :=
  Drop[Fold[If[Last[#1] < #2, Append[#1, #2], #1] &, {-∞}, s], 1];

HighWaterMarks[3][s_?VectorQ] :=
  Reap[Block[{max = -∞},
     Do[If[n > max, Sow[max = n]], {n, s}]]][[2, 1]];

HighWaterMarks[4][s_?VectorQ] :=
  DeleteDuplicates@FoldList[Max, s];
```

The test sequence is

```
SeedRandom[1234];
seq = RandomInteger[10^6, 10^6];
```

The test using [`RepeatedTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html) is

```
time[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 RepeatedTiming[result[n] = HighWaterMarks[n][seq];][[1]]
```

The average times (trimmed mean) are

```
times = time /@ Range[4]

(* {0.220534, 0.840865, 0.338244, 0.0717656} *)
```

The relative times are

```
times/Min[times]

(* {3.07298, 11.7168, 4.71317, 1.} *)
```

Verifying that all results are identical

```
SameQ @@ (result /@ Range[4])

(* True *)
```

The number of high-water marks is

```
Length@result[1]

(* 14 *)
```